# JavaScript Date() - getting / offsetting multiple timezones

Tags: javascript, date

I'm not a noobie to js, but haven't done a ton of work with dates.

I need to get "now" in three GMT time zones (offsets +5:30, +7, +8) and I'm confused as to whether `var now = new Date();` would be the local "now" anywhere in the world, or do I need to calculate a separate "now" for each timezone to do my evaluations based on GMT or UTC.

I then need to compare "now" var against a date (November 19, 2019 10:00 AM) in those three timezone. For example,

```
let now = new Date();
let presale530 = new Date('11-19-2019 10:00 AM GMT+5:30'); // Bangalore
if (now > presale530) {
  // start the presale in Bangalore
}
```

The above needs to happen simultaneously with a different time zone:

```
let now = new Date();
let presale7 = new Date('11-19-2019 10:00 AM GMT+7'); // Jakarta
if (now > presale7) {
  // start the presale in Jakarta
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` <strike>returns the date and time in the timezone specified by the browser.</strike> edit: As pointed out by RobG, this is wrong. `new Date()` returns an object with the actual UTC time. It is the methods like `toString()` or plain get methods that depends on the browser/system.  Each browser behaves differently, some are in the settings, some inherit from the system timezone.

So it depends on your business logic. It seems like you are targeting different locations, so your `now` will work fine assuming that the user do not tamper with their devices/browsers timezone and let them set to whichever location they are at. If you have some other code to determine their location via ip, then serve the respective code to the area, instead of relying on their browser/system settings, then your `now` will not be sufficient. Use `Date().getTime()` instead to get absolute epoch time then format it in the timezone you want.

So it depends whether you trust the user, and if you have a better way to locate the user and serve the appropriate code.

Edit:
After relooking at your question, it seems like you are writing 3 sets of code for 3 separate pages. I assume you have a backend detecting ip and serving 3 different sites, perhaps with different .us, .ca, .cn, etc..

In that case, you would want each site to start the presale at the same time and not depend on the browser/computer setting. That is a business logic you have to clarify. If this is the case, it is best to use `getTime()` and format it in the timezone you desire for comparison.

Comment: You are right. Yes, it returns the object with the UTC time. It is the common get methods that return local values. getTime() will return the UTC time. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is what I cobbled together before I say your answers. Will this work? https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/xke09j1y/23/. It works here if I manually change the dates, but I need to be 100% sure these will kick in and off in those timezones at the specified times.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused as to whether var now = new Date(); would be the local "now" anywhere in the world, or do I need to calculate a separate "now" for each timezone to do my evaluations based on GMT or UTC.

Dates are UTC, so "now" will be the same regardless of the local offset with the caveat that the system clocks must be correctly set. The system timezone offset is only used where local values are assumed (plain *set* methods, parsing strings without an offset, etc.).

*Date.prototype.toString* returns a string based on the host system timezone offset and the plain *get* methods return local values.

The *getUTC* methods return UTC values and should all be the same regardless of host system settings (with the same caveat as above).

However, if you have a string like "November 19, 2019 10:00 AM" without a timezone offset, then you'll have to manually parse and apply the offset (either write your own function or use a library).

E.g. A function to parse a string like "November 19, 2019 10:00 AM" as UTC and apply a timezone offset like +05:30 is:

```js
/* Parse string in format MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm a as UTC and apply
** a timezone offset in format +/-HH:mm)
**
** @param {string} s - string to parse
** @param {string} offset - +/-HH:mm default '+00:00'
** @returns {Date}
*/
function myParse(s, offset = '+00:00') {
  let months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun',
                'jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
  let b = s.split(/[ ,:]+/);
  let m = months.indexOf(b[0].toLowerCase().substr(0,3));
  let hr = +b[3];
  let min = +b[4];
  let ap = b[5];
  hr = (hr % 12) + (ap.toLowerCase() == 'am'? 0 : 12);

  // Get hr and min of timezone offset with sign
  let c = offset.split(':');
  let oSign = c[0] < 0? '-' : '+';
  let oHr = +c[0]
  let oMin = c[1] * (oSign == '-'? -1 : 1);

  // Create date using values as UTC, apply offset
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[2], m, b[1], hr + oHr, min + oMin)); 
}

// +00:00 - i.e. UTC
console.log(myParse("November 19, 2019 10:00 AM"));
// +05:30
console.log(myParse("November 19, 2019 10:00 AM", '+05:30'));
// -07:00
console.log(myParse("November 19, 2019 12:00 AM", '-07:00'));
// Difference in dates is 12:30, which is the difference in timezone offsets
```

However, if you have other date arithmetic to perform or different formats to support, a library may help.

Comment: this is what I cobbled together before I say your answers. Will this work? https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/xke09j1y/23/. It works here if I manually change the dates, but I need to be 100% sure these will kick in and off in those timezones at the specified times.

Comment: @KirkRoss—if you have another question, please put it in another post. `new Date('11-19-2019 10:00 AM GMT+5:30')` produces an invalid date in the first browser I tested.